# Running docker from bash script

Tags: bash, docker, gatk

I am using a tool (gatk) distributed as a docker image and try to use its commands in a shell script.
I run the docker in detached mode.

```
sudo docker run --name my_container -d -v ~/test:/gatk/data -it broadinstitute/gatk:4.1.9.0
```

Then I run the commands from shell script

```
#!/bin/bash
docker exec my_container gatk command1
wait
docker exec my_container gatk command2
```

command2 needs input from command1 so I use wait, but still command2 is executed before command 1 is finished.
I also tried

```
#!/bin/bash
docker exec my_container gatk command1
docker wait my_container
docker exec my_container gatk command2
```

but then the script does not continue running after command1 is completed.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by *"needs input"*. Input in what form? Parameters? Files? `stdin`? Keyboard? How would you run the two commands if there was no docker involved?

Comment: The second command takes a file created by the 1st command. The docker runs in detached mode.

Comment: When you run docker in is detached mode, the process goes into background. If you do not run in detached mode second command will wait.

Comment: @DigvijayS Thanks, I run docker from a terminal and would like to disconnect after running my script. Can I do it without using detached mode? Is there another way  I can wait for the 1st command?

Comment: run docker without detached using  `nohup docker exec my_container gatk command1 && docker exec my_container gatk command2 &`

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve it. The problem was is that when I ran docker exec I did not define it to receive input from the shell. Adding -i flag to docker exec solved the problem. Here is the full solution.

I start docker in detached mode

```
sudo docker run --name my_container -d -v ~/test:/gatk/data -it broadinstitute/gatk:4.1.9.0
```

Now I can close the terminal, the docker container is up and running and I can use it in a new terminal.
I generate a bash script called myscript.sh with the following code.

```
#!/bin/bash
docker exec -i my_container gatk command1
wait
docker exec -i my_container gatk command2
```

I run the script, disown it and close the terminal.

```
./myscript.sh&disown;exit
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run both commands in a single shot:

```
docker run image /bin/bash -c "gatk command1 && gatk command2"
```